# CSS is not working for a media query in WooCommerce under WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to style site branding for a media query screen with a maximum width of 768 pixels, but it's not picking it up. I tried:

```css
/* Without media query */

.custom-logo-link img {
  width: 80%!important;
  margin-bottom: -4em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .storefront-primary-navigation {
    clear: both;
    height: 36px !important;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 0!important;
    margin-top: -2em;
  }

  .custom-logo-link img {
    width: 62%!important; /* This is what not changing. I need this from 80 to 62. */
    margin-bottom: -4em;
    display:flex; // Tried block inline
  }
}

  /* The same CSS for .site-branding too
  I tried in theme customizer and child CSS, but it’s not changing. */
```

```php
  // Another option tried
  add_action('storefront_header', 'storefront_site_branding', 20);

  function storefront_site_branding() {
    echo '<style>
      @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .site-branding {
          margin-bottom: -2.5em;
          width: 32.739%!important;
        }
      }
      </style>';
  }
```

But it didn't work. What is the solution?

Comment: it looks fine, can you share link or more information

Comment: working on wamp.using a function makes image disappear/checked for conflict with plugins still css not working

Comment: Since its screen rule your device prob have cache ? Try in incognito window ? Or try  @media (max-width: 768px) {} While i work on local project i prefer disableing cache check this - https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/apache-web-server/turning-off-caching-using-htaccess?aid=1656214

Comment: i did that along with different browsers

Comment: Near *"display:flex"*: `//` is *not* a valid comment character in CSS (it may silently fail in various ways). Is it only present here and not in the real code?

Answer (score 0):

Try using media queries for sizes above 768 pixels too. Something like this:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    .custom-logo-link img {
        width: 80%!important;
        margin-bottom: -4em;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .storefront-primary-navigation {
         clear: both;
         height: 36px !important;
         float: right;
         margin-left: 0!important;
         margin-top: -2em;
    }

    .custom-logo-link img {
         width: 62%!important;
         margin-bottom: -4em;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes still same .............